# Passing Complex object with inner complex object to GET Web API endpoint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, get

I've one question on how to pass complex object to Web API GET method, where complex object has one more inner object. I've seen examples where there are no inner objects and no one is talking about the complex object which has inner object and what is the best way of achieving that. I have something which is working but I want to know if there are better ways of doing it.

Example without inner object –

```
public class Name
{
    string FName {get; set;}
    public string LName { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public void Test([FromUri]Name details)
{
    Console.WriteLine(details.ToString());
}
```

Postman - *http://localhost:XXXX/api/NameSearch/Test**?FName=Soumen&LName=Banerjee***

Here is the example with complext object having inner object.

Example –

```
public class Address
{
      public string Street { get; set; }
      public string Zipcode { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
      public string FName {get; set;}
      public string LName { get; set; }
      public Address Address { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public void Test([FromUri]Name details)
{
    Console.WriteLine(details.ToString());
}
```

Postman - *http://localhost:XXXX/api/NameSearch/Test**?details.fName=Soumen&details.lName=Banerjee&details.address.street=Mains%20Height&details.address.zipcode=12345***

So here you can see that, I've to pass the values using fully qualified name, property and value e.g. **details.fname=Soumen or details.address.zipcode=12345**. This is different than what I've done in my first example. So, I want to know are there better ways of doing this or this is the only way to pass complex object with inner object(s)? Thank you.

Comment: HttpPost is better when you need to pass object

Comment: @NajiMakhoul - I know, but as mentioned, it is for getting/searching records and not for any update so using POST for getting a record is not a good practice.